# Gitolite interfaces for managing users, repositories and history?

Tags: git, interface, gitolite

I have been looking for current gitolite interfaces but wasn't able to find anything usable.

It has to run on our linux server and be able to:
manage users,
manage repositories,
manage branches,
show history/log

Is there anything that provides these features?

Comment: It seems you'd want Gitlab, pagure or similar web-based solution.

Comment: I guess you mean graphical web-based interfaces? Because gitolite provides an awesome text-based interface via commits to the gitolite-admin repo.